# Perform callback after destroying child records only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

```
class MyTask < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, as: :ownerable, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true

  before_save :set_some_data
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ownerable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

In the :set_some_data method, we actually take the values from all the jobs belonging to the MyTask object and perform some calculations and save  the result in a column (actually, just a `self.column_name = calculated_value`, not actually calling save).

The problem is that the UPDATE on the column happens before any jobs marked for destruction ie with `"_destroy" => 1` in the `params`. And so obviously, it includes data from the deleted jobs, which is incorrect.

I am currently doing the following - change callback to:

```
after_save :set_some_data

def set_some_data
  #Do stuff
  # WARNING: Don't use any method that will trigger an after_save callback. Infinite loop otherwise.
  self.update_columns(column_name: calculated_value)
end
```

It does what I want. But is this a good solution? Can you suggest some better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with with after_destroy and put the method in job.rb this will make sure when child deleted(job) it will call the parent to update the value

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ownerable, polymorphic: true, optional: true

  after_destroy :update_parent


  def update_parent
    # check your parent model
    self.ownerable.update_columns(column_name: calculated_value)
  end
end
```

for more detail callback you can check [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) and

Comment: But in this case, suppose I destroy 3 jobs of the parent MyTask object, then this callback will run 3 times. It will also not run on creating or updating jobs, which means that I will still need to have my before_save callback.

This doesn't seem very efficient to me. Upvoted because it will do the job required.

Comment: yes, I have same case with yours, I use after_save for create and update, it seems not efficient (yes I agree) especially if there are many jobs within one parent but the point here "save transaction" meaning if child changed, then the parent should be updated directly, I open and also want to learn for this case if there is another option that save transaction and effective since I have many case like this